# What are the exact memes that are being referenced in the new “SpongeBob SquarePants Masterpiece Memes” collection of action figures?

Tags: object-identification, meme, spongebob-squarepants

Nickelodeon has just released a new line of action figures called the “[SpongeBob SquarePants Masterpiece Memes](https://www.complex.com/pop-culture/2019/04/nickelodeon-releases-official-spongebob-meme-figures)” line. Pic below. What are the exact memes that this commemorative collection is commemorating?

[image: The “SpongeBob SquarePants Masterpiece Memes” collection.]

Comment: One of the three episodes I watched had an evil Spongebob spawning from a magic pencil. Seems on-topic, although I don't know whether the memes referenced here are SFFnal. Cf [this meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/344/98028)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From left to right, according to the "Meme Merchandise" section of [SpongeBob subculture over knowyourmeme.com](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/subcultures/spongebob-squarepants):

- [Mocking SpongeBob](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/mocking-spongebob)
- [Handsome Squidward](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/handsome-squidward-squidward-falling): Involves Squidward becoming handsome after getting his face smashed by a door, and a flying shoe.
- [Imagination SpongeBob](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/imagination-spongebob)
- [Surprised Patrick](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/surprised-patrick)
- [Handsome Squidward (again)](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/handsome-squidward-squidward-falling)
- [SpongeGar/Caveman SpongeBob](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/spongegar-primitive-sponge-caveman-spongebob): Apparently comes from an episode involving time travel. On-topic.